# SQL, using SELECT with checkbox C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to search my SQL database with checkboxes.

Let me explain: I have several checkboxes, each checkbox has a value (column name); the user should be able to select what to search in database with checkboxes.

Normally it should be like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select regnr, benamning, dimension, profil from verkstad.dackforvaring where regnr like ('%"+ TextBox1.Text +"%')";
```

I want one checkbox for regnr, one checkbox for benamning and so on.

If just checkbox for regnr is active, then the search should be only for regnr.
(`SELECT checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 FROM etc`)

Can this be done, and how? :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Whst is `regnr`, `benamning`? As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You want the columns to be part of search criteria? Like `where regnr like 'add%' and benamning like 'dfds%'` ? or they should be only part of Select Column list ?

Comment: So the checkboxes checked define which columns are included in the SELECT list. Of course if you want to have multiple WHERE conditions then you need multiple TextBoxes (one for each condition) and you should also be able to choose between AND/OR logical operation

Comment: Regnr and benamning is just columns in the table. I want that each checkbox represent a column. If just checkbox that represent "regnr" is active, then the search will just be "select regnr from. If also checkbox that represent benamning is active then the search will be "select regnr ,benamning from.

Answer (score 2):

The *easiest* way to do it is to build your SQL dynamically, adding additional `WHERE` clauses and columns to your `SELECT`.  However, that exposes a SQL injection vulnerability since you allow user-inputted text to be injected into your SQL, and you have to worry about apostrophes and other punctuation that could invalidate your SQL.

A more stable way is to account for any possible column in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT regnr, benamning, dimension, profil 
FROM verkstad.dackforvaring where
   (@regnr     IS NOT NULL AND regnr     LIKE '%' + @regnr     + '%') OR
   (@benamning IS NOT NULL AND benamning LIKE '%' + @benamning + '%') OR
   (@dimension IS NOT NULL AND dimension LIKE '%' + @dimension + '%') OR
   (@profil    IS NOT NULL AND profil    LIKE '%' + @profil    + '%')
```

And pass each value as a parameter (using `DBNull.Value` for columns that weren't checked).

You *could* dynamically add the lines to the `WHERE` clause depending on which columns were checked, and dynamically add columns to the `SELECT` clause, but that would be the general idea versus concatenating strings (especially the input values - make sure those are added via parameters).

Comment: +1, but you can build a parametrized query dynamically, so it doesn't necessarily expose you to SQL injection.   After all, an ORM probably builds queries dynamically in this way.   The key point is that when building the query, use parameters rather than concatenating strings that come from user input.

Comment: @Joe True - I added that as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: since `WHERE` clause is also dependant on checked `checkBoxes`, i have edited my answer and expanded `Dictionary` to include values for `where` clause. Bear in mind that this is generic solution and better to be used as hint, not as real solution.

---

First of all, never use command text string concatenation and learn about parameterized queries.
About your question, I would suggest `Dictionary` approach. 
Make dictionary with your `CheckBox` names as keys and Tuple containing column names and textbox with value as values.

So, define dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>();
```

Fill it with values:

```
dict.Add(checkBox1.Name, new Tuple<string, string>("regnr", TextBox1.Text)); 
dict.Add(checkBox2.Name, new Tuple<string, string>("benamning", TextBox2.Text));
dict.Add(checkBox3.Name, new Tuple<string, string>("dimension", TextBox3.Text));
//etc..
```

in your form, get names of checked checkboxes with something like this:

```
var checkedCheckBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cb => cb.Checked).Select(cb => cb.Name);
```

Now, find matching columns from your dictionary. From that list make column names for `select` and `where` clause.

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> columnNames = dict.Where(pair => checkedCheckBoxes.Contains(pair.Key)).Select(pair => pair.Value).ToList();
string selectColumnNames = string.Join(", ", columnNames.Select(t => t.Item1).ToArray());

string whereClause = "";
for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count(); i++)
{
    if (i > 0) whereClause +=" and ";
    whereClause += string.Format("{0} = @{0}", columnNames[i]);
}
```

Finally, make command text with this.

```
string commandText = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM erkstad.dackforvaring WHERE {1}", selectColumnNames, whereClause);
```

and execute **parameterized** sqlCommand, passing parameter values from Tuple.Item2

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = commandText;

foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@" + columnName.Item1), columnName.Item2);
}


var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: The checkboxes affect the WHERE clause, too.

Comment: @DStanley, ok, I have edited my answer to include where part...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to dynamicly build up your sql string. For example if you just want to search for regnr, because this is the only active checkbox you can do the following:

```
string sql = "select {0} from verkstad.dackforvaring where regnr like('%@PARAM_1%')";

if (checkboxRegnr.Checked)
  sql = string.Format(sql, "regnr");
```

This is just the simplest example and you need to extend this for your needs.

Further notice that you should use DbParameter instead of directly inject the Textbox1.Text into your sql. As Jamiec pointed out in his comment, this is a [security lack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).